# Problems using the library quant mod

Tags: r

Even when I call the correct object using the library, I am unable to recover the last value. The code doesn't complain or show a mistake, nevertheless it is not working.

```
library("quantmod")

 v = c("INR", "GBP", "RUB", "MXN", "CAD", "EUR")

 currencies <- data.frame(
              currency = v,
              value = 1:6,
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #convert budgets to usd
         for(i in 1:nrow(currencies)){
         s_string <- paste0(currencies$currency[i],"/" ,"USD") 
         s_string2 <- paste0(currencies$currency[i] ,"USD") 
         getFX("CHF/USD")
         currencies$value[i] <- tail(s_string2,1)
   }
```

In the last line, it is not working in that way. But if I write directly the name of the variable is working

Instead of

```
      tail(s_string2,1)
```

This

```
      tail(EURUSD,1)
```

I would like to have a dataset with the name of the currencies (I have that) and the values (I don't have that.)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem is the way I am passing the string, solved in this way:

```
  currencies$value[i] <- tail(eval(as.name(s_string2)),1)
```